# How do I get all four keyValue pairs using RestAssured for CreateUser Post request

Tags: java, post, postman, pojo, createuser

Response using RestAssured doesn't include all four key value pairs, it works fine in Postman and returns all four values.

- Bottom right is the response of my post CREATE USER query https://reqres.in/
  Top left I have attempted to write a code that runs the same query using RestAssured
- Bottom left shows the log.

[image]

```
UserTests Class
// Create user request number 7 (post request)
    System.out.println("test_get_single_user_by_ID_returns_http_404() - User Story 7  CREATE");
    
    Response createUser = (Response) given().queryParam("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .body(au)
    .when().log().all().post("/api/users")
    .then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(201).extract().response();
    
    
    String createUserResponse = createUser.asString();
    
    System.out.println(createUserResponse);
    JsonPath js = ReUseableMethods.rawToJson(createUserResponse);
    System.out.println(au.getCreatedAt());
    au.getJob();
    System.out.println(js);
```

Response in console:

```
{"id":"117","createdAt":"2020-07-05T11:17:26.597Z"}

required response
{
    "name": "RAK",
    "job": "Automation testing",
    "id": "683",
    "createdAt": "2020-06-26T07:36:28.264Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your Content Type setting. Content type must be passed as a header and not as a queryParam.

This will return the full object:

```
  Response createUser = (Response) given().header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body(au)
                .when().log().all().post("https://reqres.in/api/users")
                .then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(201).extract().response();
```